# Finding the equation of 2D lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Find the equation of a 2D line which...

A) Passes through the point A(0,-2) and is perpendicular to the vector v=(-2,-5)

B)Passes through the points A(2,-3) and B(3,-4)

C)Passes through the point A (2,-4) and is parallel to the line y=-2x-5

I tried to do these questions and so far I only understood how to do B) which is y=-x-1

Comment: The equation of a line is $$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$ where $(x_0,y_0)$ is any point on your line.  So all you have to figure out is how to find the slope $m$.  Can you do that part yourself?  For any of the parts?

Comment: **MASSIVE HINT:** How do you find a slope for a line? If you know the answer to this, then it should help you find the slope of a line in any linear equation. Does $ m=\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ sound familiar?

Comment: @Bye_World my bad it was (2,-3)

Answer (score 1):

For A and C,
I would use
the point-slope form
of a line.
It states that
a line through
$(u, v)$
with slope $m$
has the form
$y-v = (x-u)m
$.

Note that this is true
when $x=u$ and $y=v$,
so it passes through the point.
Also note that
the equation can be written
$\dfrac{y-v}{x-u}
=m
$,
so its slope is $m$.

The vector through
$(-2, -5)$
(and, I assume,
$(0, 0)$)
has slope
$\dfrac{-5}{-2}
=\dfrac{5}{2}
$,
so the slope of the
normal to it
has a value which is
its negative reciprocal
which is
$\dfrac{-2}{5}$.

For C,
the slope of the line
$y=-2x-5$
is
$-2$,
and it passes through
$ (2,-4)$.

You should now be able to
get your answers.

Comment: so c) is y=-2x?

Answer (score 0):

For A), the most direct way is to use the vector form of the equation: if $(x_A,y_A)$ are the coordinates of the point $A$, and $\vec n$ is a normal vector, the equation is
$$\overrightarrow{AM}\cdot \vec n=0,\quad\text{i.e.}\quad 2x+5(y+2)=0.$$

For B), if the given poibts have different abscissae, there's a formula, which is a translation of the colinearity of the vectors  $\overrightarrow{AM}$ and $\overrightarrow{AB}$: 
$$\frac{y -y_A}{x-x_A}=\frac{y_B -y_A}{x_B-x_A}\iff y=\frac{y_B -y_A}{x_B-x_A}(x-x_A)+y_A.$$

For C), use the formula for the eqaution of a line passing through $A$, with prescribed slope $m$:
$$y=m(x-x_A)+y_A.$$

Comment: so A) y=-2/5x+2

Comment: With one more $-$ sign!

Comment: Pardon me, what sign?